# java regular expressions matching specific urls

Tags: java, android, regex

I once built a program in php that used very specific regular expressions to match links, however that pattern doesnt seem to work in java, Im trying to find the java equivalent of

```
"~http://(bit.ly|t.co)~"
```

in php this would would match links such as http://t.co/UURRNlrK and http://bit.ly/AenG5W what would be a java equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
String str = "http://t.co/UURRNlrK";
String p = "(http://(t\.co|bit\.ly).*)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if(matcher.find())
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Output = `http://t.co/UURRNlrK`

if `str =  "http://bit.ly/AenG5W"`

Output = `http://bit.ly/AenG5W`

Here is a nice [Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for java.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://(bit\.ly|t\.co)/\w*
```

I think this one would result same as the upper ones

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
String str = "http://bit.ly/asdfsd";

if(str.matches("http://(bit\.ly|t\.co).+")){
    System.out.println("hurray");
}
```

Comment: The dots in the matches for bit.ly and t.co need to be escaped, like this "http://(bit\.ly|t\.co).+" otherwise it would also match bitfly, for example.